# Scaling down a child view takes same height

Tags: android, view, kotlin, android-nestedscrollview

I am trying to display texts in a `TextView` in `NestedScrollView` such that texts bigger than the screen get displayed after scaling down the `TextView` it self.
Here is my code -

```
        val content = findViewById(R.id.content) as TextView
        content.setText(R.string.large_text)

        content.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener {
            Log.d("Height", content.height.toString())//1584:6501
            val factor = 1584f / 6501;
            content.scaleX = factor;
            content.scaleY = factor;
        }
```

Where my device screen height is `1584px` and `TextView`'s content height is `6501px`

The problem is `NestedScollView` sill scrolls after scaling down the height of `TextView` to the device screen height.

I also tried calling invalidate() and requestLayout() on TextView and its parent `NestedScrollView` but no luck. `ScrollView` keeps scrolling.

Also I tried extending `TextView` and overriding `onMeasure()` method as

```
override fun onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec: Int, heightMeasureSpec: Int) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec)
        val parentWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec)
        val parentHeight = 1584// MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec)
        this.setMeasuredDimension(parentWidth, parentHeight)
    }
```

But then `NestedScrollView` stops scrolling and Content in the `TextView` was not showing all contents. Probably `TextView` was taking same height as screen and hence not displaying all texts.

How can I force 'TextView' to take scaled height after scaling down so `NestedScrollView` don't scroll?
Any help will be highly appreciated , Thanks in advance!

**Edit**
Here is my XML code-

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.admin.canary.KotlinActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_kotlin">
    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Use Hierarchy Viewer and make sure which element is the one with height bigger than your screen..

Comment: @ShadyAtef  Obviously its the Textview with more content(String) more than to fit with the height of the screen.

Comment: Okay, can you provide the layout xml, It interests me to investigate.

Answer (score 0):

Your observation is just the implemented behavior. Applying transformations to a view does not actually change any properties of it. So in your case the view is only scaled down in `onDraw()` while the actual size does not change.

Overriding the `onMeasure()` method will then set a fixed size for the text view itself, without fitting the text into this size. It just cuts of the text itself.

You should also take into consideration, that the text view is already scrollable or at least that the nested scroll view should define `android:layout_height="match_parent"`.

---

Fitting the text view efficiently is not too easy. You could use some library for this. [*AutoFitTextView*](https://github.com/AndroidDeveloperLB/AutoFitTextView) supports the behavior you're looking for. You'd have to replace your complete layout with a `com.vj.widgets.AutoResizeTextView` and let this match the screen size.

Comment: I guess AutoFitTextView is not solving my problem. Actually I am trying to render create book reader where I am using TextView to render individual pages. Suppose I have each page(which is in html) which has 720*1280 dimension with textSize 26px . How can I show the same appearance on the another screen with dimensions different than the above? I was trying something like creating a TextView with same dimention and scaling to fit in the screen for other dimensions